# Angular modal dialog directive not working in Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

i'm using angular directive to display modal dialog. This directive works as expected in web application. I integrated that with Ionic Application and the modal dialog fires only once.  Here is my code snippet

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.directive('modalDialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        replace: true, // Replace with the template below
        transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.dialogStyle = {};
            if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
            if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
            scope.hideModal = function () {
                scope.show = false;
            };
        },
        template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>  <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>  <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>    <div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div>    <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div>  </div></div>"
    };
})
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modalShown = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function () {
        $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
    };

}]);
```

In Html Page:

```
 <button ng-click='toggleModal()'>Open First Dialog</button>
  <modal-dialog show="modalShown"  width='200px' height='60%'>
            <p>Modal Content Goes here</p>
  </modal-dialog>
```

Any idea? Or any suggestion much appreciate..

Comment: Hi, Have you tried to remove `ionic` dependency and test if is it working or not? Or in the html, have you used for example `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> your button and directive should be here </div>`?

Comment: Yes.. This works without ionic dependency. Any idea to sort it out?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but let me tell you what I did. I've created blank ionic project and I copied your javascript code and pasted it in `app.js` file. After that I took your html and put them inside div that reference your controller like so `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> your button and directive should be here  </div>`. After that I placed everything inside `<ion-content></ion-content>` and its working for me.

Comment: It works only for the first time. when you click it again it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Try to use ionic command `ionic serve` to run it in browser, and see if any errors appear in the console of the browser.